# (Jboss 5) Annotated Message Driven beans not detected/deployed in War file

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss5.x

Got the following annotated mdb which works when deployed as a jar(even without the ejb.jar.xml) into Jboss but doesn't work when deployed within a war, mdbs seem to be ignored.I have an existing project which is a war and would like to just inject as is today as the mdb needs to reference the jars in the lib folder & also classses in war. I am basically looking for the easiest option to for it to work so I dont need make much changes to the existing war structure. Any ideas please ?

```
@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(
                        propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/testqueue1")
        })
public class MessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

 public void onMessage(Message message) {

        System.out.println("Received..............:" + message.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need to define your web dynamic project as version 3 so you can deploy also EJBs and MDBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EJB 3.1** supports EJB deployment in `.war` files. No there's no support for **EJB 3.1** in JBoss AS 5.x.